# sorting a text file with comma separated column

Tags: sorting

I have a multi column text file with statistics such as mean, median, mode, etc. I can sort this file conveniently with the sort -n -k [column] but run into an obstacle when the statistics contain a multi-modal column; example

```
mean median mode
2    4      4
3    4.5    2,1
4    3      3
2    2      1,2,3
3    2      3
```

running sort -n -k 3 produces

```
mean median mode
2    4      3
3    2      3
4    3      3
3    4.5    2,1
2    2      1,2,3
```

I would like (ideally)

```
mean median mode
3    4.5    2,1
2    2      1,2,3
4    3      3
3    2      3
2    4      4
```

I am open to reformating the text file itself and thought about replacing the "," in multi modal columns with "." to trick the sort function but this does not work when the column is trimodal or when the listed modes are out of order. Any way to do this without a script?

Comment: What's the context of this sorting? You mentioned `sort -n -k` so I'm supposing you are in `bash`?

Comment: Your question boils down to "how do I sort `2,1` before `1,2,3`. Further, you seem to want to do this using the most simple of text replacement tools or shell utilities ("without a script"). I'd say that's a futile approach. You could however replace all occurring values of `mode` with sortable placeholders (e.g. numbers), sort according to those placeholders and restore their initial values.

Comment: @lurker: `sort` works fine without `bash` but I'd be with you if you suggested "shell scripting" as a tag. :)

Comment: It is bash shell and the comma delimited list of modes can easily be sort by the scrip that outputs these statistics. Im wondering if there's a clever way to pipe to awk when sorting on the (possibly) multi-modal column

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah you're right, I just tossed `bash` out there as an example. I should have said more generally, "shell scripting".